# How to store countdown timer value in a variable?

Tags: java, android

So, I have a countdown timer in my activity. Now, I have a button which opens another activity. When that button is clicked I need to store the current countdown timer value, and start a countdown timer in the second activity from that saved value. I was thinking to pass the time using the Intent but I don't know what value to pass. How can I do that? My timer:

```
public String formatTime(long millis) {  
        String output = "00:00";  
        long seconds = millis / 1000;  
        long minutes = seconds / 60;  

        seconds = seconds % 60;  
        minutes = minutes % 60;  

        String sec = String.valueOf(seconds);  
        String min = String.valueOf(minutes);  

        if (seconds < 10)  
            sec = "0" + seconds;  
        if (minutes < 10)  
            min= "0" + minutes;  

        output = min + " : " + sec;  
        return output;
    }
```

And in onCreate method:

```
// New timer for 40 minutes, starts after initialization
        new MyCount(2400000, 1000) 
        {
            // Updates the text on your "scoreboard" every second
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
            {
                vreme.setText("" + formatTime(millisUntilFinished));
            }

            public void onFinish() 
            {

            }
        }.start();
    }

    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
         public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
             super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
         }

         public void onFinish() {


         }
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             vreme.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         }
```

Comment: Why can't you pass millisUntilFinished as an extra in the `Intent`?

Comment: Maybe just `intent.putExtra(String,String)`? And in `onReceive()` do `intent.getStringExtra(String)`

Comment: What string? Isn't millisUntilFinished a Long?

Comment: @Simon So, when I pass millisUntilFinished what value will I get on my activity end? Lets say 550 seconds are left...will I get 550 seconds? I don't understand completely how that works.

Comment: No, it's milliseconds so you will get 550000 milliseconds.

Comment: Ok then `intent.putExtra(String,Long)` and `intent.getLongExtra(String)`. The string here will be a key for your value.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the information you're looking for is available from the CountDownTimer. If you don't need to be very precise with your time then you can just pull the string out of vreme.

Assuming you want to be more precise than that, I would suggest saving a timestamp when the timer starts, and then get the difference between that and the current time when you need to know how much time has elapsed. Check out [uptimeMillis()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#uptimeMillis%28%29) or [elapsedRealtime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime%28%29) depending on your needs.

Comment: No, couple second does not metter. I have a 20 minutes window in which a user needs to complete the game. So, i don't think couple of second will be that bad.

Comment: Then you can just use vreme.getText().toString() to pull your timer string out. You'd have to do a little parsing to get the time from this though. Alternatively you could add something to your onTick method that will store the most recent millisUntilFinished which you can then pass to the intent.

Comment: OK, I did that, but how can I parse from String (I get something like 19:42) to long?

Answer (score 0):

OK, to answer myself. Here's what I did. In my first activity I did all the stuff in original post, plus I added this, in MyCount method, right below vreme.setText....:

```
currentTime = millisUntilFinished;
```

And previously I declared in my activity scope:

```
long currentTime;
```

After that, on my button onClickListener I did this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Game1.this, Game2.class);
                i.putExtra("timeCode", currentTime);
                startActivity(i);
```

After that in my Game2 class's onCreate method (also declared long variable):

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        if(extras !=null) {
           currentTime = extras.getLong("timeCode");
        }
```

Then this (it's basically the same code from the Game1 class, only one change, my passed variable instead that 240000 value):

```
new MyCount(currentTime, 1000) 
    {
        // Updates the text on your "scoreboard" every second
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
        {
            vreme.setText("" + formatTime(millisUntilFinished));
        }

        public void onFinish() 
        {

        }
    }.start();
}




public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
     public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
         super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
     }

     public void onFinish() {


     }
     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         vreme.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }
```

And it works like a charm!